# Generate combinations with specified order with itertools.combinations

Tags: pandas, python-itertools

I used `itertools.combinations` to generate combinations for a dataframe's index. I'd like the combinations in specified order --> `(High - Mid - Low)`

Example

```
from itertools import combinations
d = {'levels':['High', 'High', 'Mid', 'Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'Mid'], 'converted':[True, True, True, False, False, True, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_ = pd.crosstab(df['levels'], df['converted'])
```

df_

```
converted   False   True
levels      
High        0       2
Low         2       1
Mid         1       1
```

`list(combinations(df_.index, 2))` returns `[('High', 'Low'), ('High', 'Mid'), ('Low', 'Mid')]`

I'd like the third group to be `('Mid', 'Low')`, how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) first, but first and second values in list are swapped:

```
order = ['High','Mid','Low']
a = list(combinations(df_.reindex(order).index, 2))
print (a)
[('High', 'Mid'), ('High', 'Low'), ('Mid', 'Low')]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Do you know why sometimes  `list(combinations(df_.reindex(order).index, 2))` will trigger `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` ? I made sure there is no variable called `list` by checking with `del list`

Comment: What is `print (list)` before `list(combinations(df_.reindex(order).index, 2))` ?

Comment: Is it `<class 'list'>` ?

Comment: @Osca - One idea, it restart your IDE working?

Comment: the first time I ran jupyter notebook it works. But weirdly, when I ran the same code the second time (in the same kernal), it gives error.

Comment: @Osca Do you have something like `combinations = [...]` *after* this `list(combinations(df_.reindex(order).index, 2))` line somewhere in the notebook? Another option is to have `df_.reindex = [...]` in similar manner but former is more likely perhaps. You can `print` the `combinations` at the very last cell of the notebook and see what it is (or printing `df_.reindex`)

Comment: @MustafaAydın I made a copy for the notebook, the copy worked. thanks